# T-SQL trigger that checks if airplane seats are taken

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I need to make a trigger that checks if an airplane seat is taken before a customer can be inserted into the table.

I have the following Trigger so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CheckIfSeatIsUnique
ON PassagierVoorVlucht
AFTER insert, update
AS
BEGIN
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 RETURN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    BEGIN TRY

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PassagierVoorVlucht P Join inserted I on P.vluchtnummer=i.vluchtnummer Where P.stoel = I.stoel)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('The chosen seat is taken', 16, 1)
      END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY()
        DECLARE @ErrorState INT = ERROR_STATE()
        RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState)
    END CATCH
END
```

The problem I have, is that the trigger checks if the seat is taken AFTER the insert was done, So the seat will always be taken no matter what.

Is there some way to check if the seat is taken before the insert is done?

Edit: It must also be possible to enter NULL on seat, because the seatnumber isn't known till a few days before the flight

Comment: would create a unique constraint on `vluchtnummer, stoel`

Comment: Use a `instead of` instead of `after`.

Comment: i cant use a unique constraint because the the column stoel can also be null.

I also tried to create an instead of, but then i get the error 'cannot create instead of update trigger, this is because table has a foreign key with cascading update'

Answer (score 1):

If you have a unique identifier on the table, you can join it into the EXISTS() query to filter out any records that were attempted to insert.

The fiddle below examples this, though it assumes you're taking care of an null handling you need to outside of this.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/93a8a

```
CREATE TRIGGER CheckIfUnique_mydata_value ON dbo.data
AFTER insert, update
AS
BEGIN
--check if we passed multiple values
  IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inserted GROUP BY value HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
  BEGIN
    RAISERROR('You tried to insert a duplicate value within the result set. Ensure you only pass unique values!', 16,1)
  END
  --check if we inserted a value that already exists that is not me (works for updates on me too!)
  IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.data m INNER JOIN inserted i ON m.value = i.value AND m.id <> i.id)
  BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Duplicate Value found',16,1)
  END
END;
```